# Dependency between APNS certificate and distribution provisioning profile?

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I have an app in the App Store with APNS.

Now, my distribution profile is broken and I can't add my device to the distribution profile. It is a generated profile by apple with the prefix XC:.

So one solution is to create a new distribution profile for a new version of my app and submit it to the App Store.

But do I then also need to create a new APNS certificate? Or will this also work with the new distribution profile?

Perhaps my actual question is: is there a relationship between the distribution profile and the APNS certificate? Or is it the app ID that is important to let the APNS work?

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in the [push notification guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html), the SSL certificate used for push notifications is independent from the distribution provisioning profile used by your app.

However, you need to ensure that your new provisioning profile provides the correct entitlements for using push notifications and their production/development environment, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingLocalAndPushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH3-SW1). Good luck.